# heroku timeout problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, pdfkit

I'm trying to generate pdf in Heroku but sometimes it takes more than 30 secs and Heroku returns timeout error.

```
def index
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.pdf 
        end
end
```

My question is how can i make it delayed job. I installed delayed jobs gem but i couldn't figure out to put action into queue.

Answer (score 1):

Delayed job is a little complicated to get setup. Try spawn It's seriously easy to get going. If it doesn't work then I will show you have to use delayed job.

Install spawn as a plugin:

```
rails plugin install https://github.com/tra/spawn.git
```

Or if you are on Rails 2

```
script/plugin install https://github.com/tra/spawn.git
```

Then all you need to do is add a method to your controller:

```
def index
    spawn_do
        #some code here that processes your pdf
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf 
    end
end
```